# Why does "==" work differently when using "new String(..)"?

Tags: java, string

Can someone explain me on how String class behaves in memory management in java. 
I have lately heard about string comparison. how does two string with == operator and equals method differ.

example: 

        `String str1 = "Hello";
        String str2 = "Hello";
        String str3 = new String("Hello");`

any suggestions on case 1 AND case3?

Comment: **any suggestions** ? . Yes, use `.equals()` always.

Comment: (But do keep up with the relevant close-votes!)

Comment: @user2864740 yes, it is

Comment: thanks for relevant replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` in Java compares the references of the 2 string objects, and not the contents. The `equals` methods does is the one that checks the content.

However, due due string interning, I believe that in the case that you listed, `str1 == str2` withh be true because there is a single instance of that string literal stored in memory.